# Arranging rest two labels on the basis of sorted text in swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting

I have three labels on the cell of of tableview.One showsname,second shows size and third shows date.I have three paramters to sort the cells of tableview i.e,name,size and date.

I want when I click name the cells get arranged showing their names in ascending order,when I click size it should get arranged according to size in ascending order,when I click date it should get arranged according to date in ascending order and the rest two labels should arranged according to their respective name ,size or date.

I am able to sort  only name, size & date.using the following code:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if(itemArray.count>1){
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            sortedNameArray = fileNameArray.sorted {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}

            sortParameter = "name"
            mediaTableView.reloadData()
            print("sorted name array",sortedNameArray)
        break
        case 1:
            sortedSizeArray = fileSizeArray.sorted {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}
            print("sorted Size array",sortedSizeArray)
           sortParameter = "size"
           mediaTableView.reloadData()
           print("1")
        case 2:
             sortedDateArray = dateArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending })
             print("sorted date array",sortedDateArray)
            sortParameter = "date"
            mediaTableView.reloadData()
        default:
            break;
        }
        }

    }
}

  func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView , cellForRowAt IndexPath:IndexPath)->UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"mediaCell",for:IndexPath) as! MediaCustomCell
        if(sortParameter == ""){
            if(itemArray.count>0){
                let urlString: String = itemArray[IndexPath.row].absoluteString
                let fileName = (urlString as NSString).lastPathComponent
                fileNameArray.append(fileName)
                do {
                    //size
                    let resources = try itemArray[IndexPath.row].resourceValues(forKeys:[.fileSizeKey])
                    let fileSize = resources.fileSize!
                    let fileSizeValue = self.transformedValue(value: fileSize)
                    cell.fileSizeLbl.text = String.init(format:"%@",fileSizeValue as! CVarArg)
                    fileSizeArray.append(cell.fileSizeLbl.text!)

                    //date
                    let fileCreatedDate = try itemArray[IndexPath.row].resourceValues(forKeys:[.creationDateKey])

                    let dateCreated = fileCreatedDate.creationDate
                    dateArray.append(dateCreated!)

                    cell.createdDateLbl.text = String.init(format:"%@",dateCreated! as CVarArg)

                    print ("filesize",fileSizeValue)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                cell.itemLbl.text = fileName
            }
        }

         //when it gets sorted on the basis of name
        else if(sortParameter == "name"){

            //name
            cell.itemLbl.text=sortedNameArray[IndexPath.row]
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let fullpath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(sortedNameArray[IndexPath.row])
            //size
            do{
            let resources = try fullpath.resourceValues(forKeys:[.fileSizeKey])
            let fileSize = resources.fileSize!
            let fileSizeValue = self.transformedValue(value: fileSize)
            cell.fileSizeLbl.text = String.init(format:"%@",fileSizeValue as! CVarArg)
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }

            //date
             let path = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(sortedNameArray[IndexPath.row])
            do{
            let fileCreatedDate = try path.resourceValues(forKeys:[.creationDateKey])
            let dateCreated = fileCreatedDate.creationDate
            cell.createdDateLbl.text = String.init(format:"%@",dateCreated! as CVarArg)
            }
            catch{
                print("error")
            }
         }


        else if(sortParameter == "size"){
           cell.fileSizeLbl.text = sortedSizeArray[IndexPath.row]





        }
        else if(sortParameter == "date"){
            cell.createdDateLbl.text = String.init(format:"%@",sortedDateArray[IndexPath.row] as CVarArg)
        }
        return cell
    }
}



func checkFileForExistence(){
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        do {
            let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            print("file urls",fileURLs)
            for files in fileURLs{
                if files.absoluteString.contains(".mp4")||files.absoluteString.contains(".mov")||files.absoluteString.contains(".MOV")||files.absoluteString.contains(".m4a"){
                    itemArray.append(files)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error while enumerating files", (error.localizedDescription))
        }
    }
```

Issue:-I am able to sort them according to name,size or date but the rest two label shows stale data.I mean if now nameLabel1 comes first,it still shows size of label2 and date of label 3.
I am too new to swift.Kindly help me to resolve this.Any kind of help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cells are reused. Since at one point you do `cell.createdDateLbl.text = something`, in the others cases, you need to do `cell.createdDateLbl.text = nil` (same for each labels). Or in the subclass of `MediaCustomCell`, override `prepareForReuse()` and set for each label their text to nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Model struct for your data instead of creating 3 different arrays.

```
struct File
{
  var name:String!
  var size:String!
  var date:Date!
}
```

Then create two arrays with the created `struct` type.

```
  var allFileDetails:[File]!
  var sortedFileDetails:[File]!
```

And you can sort the array when index changed in segment control

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
      sortedFileDetails = allFileDetails.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
    case 1:
      sortedFileDetails = allFileDetails.sorted(by: { $0.size < $1.size })
    case 2:
      sortedFileDetails = allFileDetails.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    default:
      break;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Update your `checkFileForExistence` method like this.

```
func checkFileForExistence(){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    do {
      let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
      print("file urls",fileURLs)
      for files in fileURLs{
        if files.absoluteString.contains(".mp4")||files.absoluteString.contains(".mov")||files.absoluteString.contains(".MOV")||files.absoluteString.contains(".m4a")
        {
          do {
            //name
            let fileName = (files.absoluteString as NSString).lastPathComponent
            //size
            let resources = try files.resourceValues(forKeys:[.fileSizeKey])
            let fileSize = resources.fileSize!
            let fileSizeValue = self.transformedValue(value: fileSize)
            let fileSizeStr = String.init(format:"%@",fileSizeValue as! CVarArg)
            //date
            let fileCreatedDate = try files.resourceValues(forKeys:[.creationDateKey])
            let dateCreated = fileCreatedDate.creationDate
            self.allFileDetails = [File(name: fileName, size: fileSizeStr, date: dateCreated)]
          } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
          }
        }
      }
    } catch {
      print("Error while enumerating files", (error.localizedDescription))
    }
  }
```

And use `sortedFileDetails.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAt` methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sortedFileDetails.count
  }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"mediaCell",for:IndexPath) as! MediaCustomCell
   cell.itemLbl.text = sortedFileDetails[indexPath.row].name
   cell.fileSizeLbl.text = sortedFileDetails[indexPath.row].size
   cell.createdDateLbl.text = sortedFileDetails[indexPath.row].date.description
   return cell
}
```

Comment: can u give a little more description or more explained code as I am new to swift.So,this is little hard to understand.

Comment: Changes made check above,check func checkFileForExistence().I get itemArray filled there.

Comment: Don't we need to check it conditionally, like I did as sortParameter=="name"?

Comment: Thanks a ton Sir...U saved me today!